# How can I use SignalR as Azure Service Bus transport?

Tags: signalr, servicebus, azureservicebus

I'm trying to find an alternative to using REST to read Azure Service Bus Topic Subscriptions from the browser. Seems like SignalR would be a natural for this but I can't seem to find anyone that has done it. I'm not talking about scale-out, just a SignalR Hub that would relay a set of Service Bus functions back and forth to the browser. I'm thinking of functions like, 
`addReceiver(string topic, string subscriptionID);`
`defineSubscription(string name, string subscriptionRule);`
`deleteSubscription(string name);`
`postMessageToTopic(string topic, string message);`
addReceiver would initiate an async receive on the subscription.  Each time a message came available from Service Bus, a function would be called on the JS client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code to point people in the right direction.

```
namespace SBTester
{
    public class SBHub : Hub
    {
        public void AddReceiver(string topic, string subscriptionName, string subscriptionFilter)
        {
            string messageData;

            TopicConnector.Initialize(  topic,
                                        Context.ConnectionId + "." + subscriptionName,
                                        subscriptionFilter);

            // Initiate receive loop on Service Bus
            TopicConnector.SBClient.OnMessage((receivedMessage) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    // Process the message
                    messageData = receivedMessage.GetBody<string>();
                    Clients.Caller.onMessage(topic, messageData);
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Handle any message processing specific exceptions here
                }
            });
        }
        public void DefineSubscription(string topic, string subscriptionRule)
        {
            // Call Service Bus to create Subscription on the Specified topic
        }
        public void PostMessageToTopic(string topic, string message)
        {
            // Call Service Bus to send a message
            Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(topic, message);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe bit old to comment now. If the message is sent to ServiceBus from a backend service and you want to forward it to a specific client (Web Browser) i think that calling Clients.Caller.. does not fulfill the requirement. How do you select a client when a message is received from Service Bus (potentially coming from any service)? You probably need a mapping to do something like this: Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId)...?

Answer (score 1):

From your Hub code you could directly call the Service Bus APIs to send messages or directly use Service Bus APIs from JavaScript/Browsers: http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2014/03/27/microsoft-azure-service-bus-receiving-of-messages-from-queue-and-topic-with-javascript.aspx

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. I was hoping that someone had already implemented the Hub code to call Service Bus.  (Microsoft should consider doing this!)  The stuff from Damir Dobric is good but it uses the REST API to communicate with ServiceBus which is what I'm trying to get away from.